# =IFERROR is not returning an empty cell when [value if error] is set to ""

Tags: google-sheets

In the spreadsheet linked below, I use it in the following way:

1) I first paste data into columns G through J

2) That data is then pulled into columns A through C in an almost correctly formatted way. In column C, notice that it's still returning "<>" even though I need for it to be completely blank.

Does anyone know of a way to make it actually return nothing at all into the cell instead of an error or <""> ?

Thank you!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qOlsF0KC9RsVTY9SKbROKnJ1lTbHjuTdyx8ip3taElk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You cab do it like this:

```
=IF(A2 <> "",CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2, " ", "<", J2, ">"),"")
```